# Convert Json object to List

Tags: c#, json, web

I have this Json string :

```
"UserProperties": [
     {
         "Id": "3", "values": [
             { "prop": "1" }
         ]
     },
     {
         "Id": "4", "values": [
             { "prop": "1" },
             { "prop": "2" },
             { "prop": "3" }
         ]
     }
]
```

I Want to convert this into some sort of c# string and list value like this:

```
public list<int> Id { get; set; }
public list<object> values { get; set; }
public int prop { get; set; }
```

So that i can manipulate my values :

```
foreach( int i in Id)
{
  foreach( object val in values)
  {
    var str = i + '-' + val.prop;
  }
}
```

So far what i have done is create a class that will contain those Json string. I get this code from an quite similar approach.

1. Create a wrapper class

   ```
   class Wrapper {
       [JsonProperty("UserPropertiees")]
       public ValueSet valueSet { get; set; }
   }

   class ValueSet{
       [JsonProperty("values")]
       public List<string> values {get;set;}
       public PropertySet propertySet { get; set; }
   }

   class PropertySet{
       [JsonProperty("property")]
       public List<string> property {get;set;}
   }
   ```

Comment: Sorry i forgot, i've used this method for deserializing under newton soft.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Newtonsoft's Json.NET and deserialize your JSON array into your List.

http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingCollections.htm

Answer (score 0):

As per Rob Stewart's advice, NewtonSoft.JSON is the best way to go IMO. Here's something you can put in a console app to have a play with:

```
string json = @"{""UserProperties"": [
     {
         ""Id"": ""3"", ""values"": [
             { ""prop1"": ""1"" }
         ]
     },
     {
         ""Id"": ""4"", ""values"": [
             { ""prop1"": ""1"" },
             { ""prop2"": ""2"" },
             { ""prop3"": ""3"" }
         ]
     }
]}";

            dynamic obj = JObject.Parse(json);
            foreach (var o in obj.UserProperties)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(o.Id);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
```

**EDIT**

As per your comments, here is a more complete example. Try this:

```
dynamic obj = JObject.Parse(json);
            foreach (var o in obj.UserProperties)
            {
                var sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.Append(o.Id);
                sb.Append(":");

                bool hasProps = false;

                foreach (var value in o.values)
                {
                    if (value.prop1 != null)
                    {
                        sb.Append(value.prop1);
                        sb.Append(',');
                        hasProps = true;
                    }
                    if (value.prop2 != null)
                    {
                        sb.Append(value.prop2);
                        sb.Append(',');
                        hasProps = true;
                    }
                    if (value.prop3 != null)
                    {
                        sb.Append(value.prop3);
                        sb.Append(',');
                        hasProps = true;
                    }
                }

                if (hasProps)
                {
                    sb.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1); // Remove trailing comma
                }

                Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Thanks Matt, i managed to parse those json string, however what i want is to get my hands of those Id, values, and prop1, 2, 3 entity. I mean can i still create a loop that will get me through those deeper values.

Comment: Ok, so this is really what i want to get :

Id + ":" + prop1, 2, 3 so on..
so expecting result for the above json string would be :
3: 1 and 4:1,2,3  how i will form this tag is up to me, i just really want to navigate through those values.

Comment: @under_score: see EDIT